# Replace HTML / Value inside custom tags just once

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace Custom HTML Tags such as:

```
<!-- {start %x%} -->Data<!-- {mid %x%} -->Data<!-- {end %x%} -->
```

The replace will be occur just once. In The HTML below there's two Custom HTML Tags. What is the correct regex to do it.

```
$pattern_loop = "/\<\!\-\- \{start %x%\} \-\-\>(.*)" . 
"(\<\!\-\- \{mid %x%\} \-\-\>)(.*)\<\!\-\- \{end %x%\} \-\-\>/";
$html= '<!-- {start %x%} --><br />Your account must be approved before you can login. Once approved you can log in by using your email address and password by visiting our website or at the following URL:<br /><!-- {mid %x%} --><br />Your account has now been created and you can log in by using your email address and password by visiting our website or at the following URL:<br /><!-- {end %x%} --><br /><!-- {start %x%} --><br />Your account must be approved before you can login. Once approved you can log in by using your email address and password by visiting our website or at the following URL:<br /><!-- {mid %x%} --><br />Your account has now been created and you can log in by using your email address and password by visiting our website or at the following URL:<br /><!-- {end %x%} -->';
$return= preg_replace($pattern_loop, "Content", $html, 1);

header('content-type: text/plain');
echo $return;
exit;
```

The Current Output :

```
Content
```

The Expected Output, it just replace Custom Tags once :

```
Content<br /><!-- {start %x%} --><br />Your account must be approved before you can login. Once approved you can log in by using your email address and password by visiting our website or at the following URL:<br /><!-- {mid %x%} --><br />Your account has now been created and you can log in by using your email address and password by visiting our website or at the following URL:<br /><!-- {end %x%} -->
```

Comment: I don't get your expected output, it seems just like a concatenation.

Comment: I need to replace tags just once and how to do it using preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive look ahead at the end of the regex.
I've just removed the unecessary escape and simplified the text:

```
$pattern_loop = "/<!-- \{start %x%\} -->.*?<!-- \{mid %x%\} -->.*?<!-- \{end %x%\} -->(?=.*<!-- \{start %x%\} -->)/";
$html= '<!-- {start %x%} --><br />start 1<br /><!-- {mid %x%} --><br />mid 1<br /><!-- {end %x%} --><br /><!-- {start %x%} --><br />start 2<br /><!-- {mid %x%} --><br />mid 2<br /><!-- {end %x%} --><br /><!-- {start %x%} --><br />start 3<br /><!-- {mid %x%} --><br />mid 3<br /><!-- {end %x%} -->';
$return= preg_replace($pattern_loop, "Content", $html, 1);

echo $return;
```

**output:**

```
Content<br /><!-- {start %x%} --><br />start 2<br /><!-- {mid %x%} --><br />mid 2<br /><!-- {end %x%} --><br /><!-- {start %x%} --><br />start 3<br /><!-- {mid %x%} --><br />mid 3<br /><!-- {end %x%} -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. Lookahead be a good solution, I just know using it to make sure previous character should match pattern. Don't get clear understanding about using it, It can make scope for replace too. I should give 5 vote or more.